# Java -- "error: cannot find symbol"

Tags: java, compilation, compiler-errors

I have a makefile that executes the following as part of it:

```
all:    
    CLASSPATH=$(SELF)/RT/real:$(SELF)/RT/fake:$(SELF)/RT/fake/uj javac $(SELF)/RT/real/java/lang/*.java
    CLASSPATH=$(SELF)/RT/real:$(SELF)/RT/fake:$(SELF)/RT/fake/uj javac $(DIR)/Components/UJ*.java 
    find $(SELF)/RT/real -iname "*.class" -type f >> $(SELF)/files
    find $(DIR)/Components -iname "UJCmp.class" -type f >> $(SELF)/files
    $(foreach C, $(shell echo $(CLASSES) | tr ',' ' '), \
        CLASSPATH=$(SELF)/RT/real:$(SELF)/RT/fake:$(SELF)/RT/fake/uj \
        javac $(DIR)/Components/UJ*.java $(DIR)/Components/$(C).java && \
        find $(DIR)/Components -iname "$(C).class" >> $(SELF)/files && \
    ) true
    cat $(SELF)/files | xargs $(CMD) >$(OUT)
```

But produces the following output in the terminal:

```
make -C /home/sven/git/uJVM_PhD_Project/UPNP/micropnp-contiki/build/../../uJ//BUILDENV DIR=../../uJ CCVT=../../classCvt/classCvt TOBIN=../../classCvt/tobin CLASSES= OUTPUT=__code.c
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/sven/git/uJVM_PhD_Project/UPNP/uJ/BUILDENV'
CLASSPATH=/home/sven/git/uJVM_PhD_Project/UPNP/uJ/BUILDENV//RT/real:/home/sven/git/uJVM_PhD_Project/UPNP/uJ/BUILDENV//RT/fake:/home/sven/git/uJVM_PhD_Project/UPNP/uJ/BUILDENV//RT/fake/uj javac /home/sven/git/uJVM_PhD_Project/UPNP/uJ/BUILDENV//RT/real/java/lang/*.java
CLASSPATH=/home/sven/git/uJVM_PhD_Project/UPNP/uJ/BUILDENV//RT/real:/home/sven/git/uJVM_PhD_Project/UPNP/uJ/BUILDENV//RT/fake:/home/sven/git/uJVM_PhD_Project/UPNP/uJ/BUILDENV//RT/fake/uj javac ../../uJ/Components/UJ*.java 
../../uJ/Components/UJCmp.java:81: error: cannot find symbol
        int L1 = res_name.Xlen_();
                         ^
  symbol:   method Xlen_()
  location: variable res_name of type String
../../uJ/Components/UJCmp.java:82: error: cannot find symbol
        int L2 = method_name.Xlen_();           
                            ^
  symbol:   method Xlen_()
  location: variable method_name of type String
../../uJ/Components/UJCmp.java:86: error: cannot find symbol
            b1[i] = ((byte)res_name.XbyteAt_(i));   
                                   ^
  symbol:   method XbyteAt_(int)
  location: variable res_name of type String
../../uJ/Components/UJCmp.java:89: error: cannot find symbol
            b2[i] = ((byte)method_name.XbyteAt_(i));    
                                      ^
  symbol:   method XbyteAt_(int)
  location: variable method_name of type String
../../uJ/Components/UJCmp.java:101: error: cannot find symbol
        int i, L = s.Xlen_();           //we cheat by not calling string methods - they are slow
                    ^
  symbol:   method Xlen_()
  location: variable s of type String
../../uJ/Components/UJCmp.java:102: error: cannot find symbol
        for(i = 0; i < L; i++) uj.lang.RT.consolePut((char)s.XbyteAt_(i));  
                                                            ^
  symbol:   method XbyteAt_(int)
  location: variable s of type String
6 errors
Makefile:49: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/sven/git/uJVM_PhD_Project/UPNP/uJ/BUILDENV'
../../uJ/Makefile.include:93: recipe for target '__code.c' failed
```

The weird thing is, the symbols .Xlen_() and others are included in a .java file in "/home/sven/git/uJVM_PhD_Project/UPNP/uJ/BUILDENV/RT/fake/uj/lang/MiniString.java" (and are public).
Accordingly, I'd think it is included in the classpath when trying to compile UJCmp.java. So I have no clue why it produces this error.

What am I missing?

Edit: I have a fairly weird setup and overwrite the default String class.
I'll post the source code for MiniString and String here as well:

String.java is located in "/home/sven/git/uJVM_PhD_Project/UPNP/uJ/BUILDENV/RT/real/java/lang/String.java" and the code:

```
package java.lang;
```

import uj.lang.*;

public class String extends MiniString{

```
public String(byte[] bytes){    //our constructor for raw bytes
    super(bytes);
}
```

}

MiniString.java is located in "/home/sven/git/uJVM_PhD_Project/UPNP/uJ/BUILDENV/RT/fake/uj/lang/MiniString.java" and the code:

```
    package uj.lang;

public class MiniString{

    public static String Xnew_(byte[] bytes){
        return new String(bytes);
    }

    public byte XbyteAt_(int loc){
        return 0;
    }

    public int Xlen_(){ 
        return 0;
    }

    public MiniString(byte[] bytes){}

    public int length(){
        return 0;
    }

    public char charAt(int pos){
        return 0;   
    }
}
```

Comment: The error says "variable res_name of type **String**" (emphasis mine). You say the method exists in class `MiniString`. But they don't exist in `String`. So your variable `res_name` is of the wrong type; it should be `MiniString` rather than `String`.

Comment: You are right, something I forgot to mention about that. Main post is edited with more info, String extends MiniString

Comment: `make` has nothing to do with it.